# Dropping decimal places - javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to drop the decimal places of my answer,

IE: 
17.5 (I know I can use toFixed() which will take this to 18, but this is not what I want)

I would like the answer to be "17"

The only way I can do this at the moment is by doing the following (Converting to string, etc, etc):

```
Num = 17.5;                  
Nums = Num.toString();
Numc = Nums.substring(0,2)
Numn = Number(Numc); //Displays 17
```

This then allows me to use that 17 for sums in my Javascript.

I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish this than using my current method? Something similar to toFixed() but just rounds it off to the lower option? haha

Comment: [Useful documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: Yep - sorry I didn't know about the Math.Floor guys... I'm quite new to Javascript, and didn't see this at all while researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) for positive numbers (not sure of what you want for negative ones) 
:

```
var d = Math.floor(17.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var toInteger = function(num) {
    return num >= 0 ? Math.floor(num) : Math.ceil(num);
}

toInteger(12.3); // returns 12
toInteger(-12.3); // returns -12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `toFixed(0)` to accomplish this

```
1234.5678.toFixed(0);
```

Though `Math.floor` is faster 
http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-tofixed. I included aga's function to the test